# REGEX : cut string from the four comma

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have to cut a string from the fourth stop and I can not seem to find a good way.
Sample String:
"String1","String2","String3","String4","**String5**"

I can do REGEX pattern like this:
".*?",".*?",".*?",".*?,".*?(.*?)"
and select capture group 1.

But I have several kinds of comma place.
Could someone know a better way to do this without scripts?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give several input examples, and the expected results ?

Comment: Do you have any specific language you run this regex on?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this: `(.*?,){4}(.*)` The second capture group will have string 5 and beyond.
Do you test your Regex patterns with [regex101.com](https://regex101.com)?  I find this helps a lot to test patterns.